# Creating custom JavaScript functions in V8?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'm trying to embed an custom function to my project, that uses the V8 engine, and apparently I can't make it working. I've used code, that I've found, but it seems to be outdated, or I just do it wrong. My point is to include a custom javascript file. My current code (for testing) is this :

```
    HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

    v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
    global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "test", v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked(),
        v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, test));

    Handle<Context> context = Context::New(isolate);
    Persistent<Context> persistent_context(isolate, context);

    Context::Scope context_scope(context);
    const char* data = "test";
    Handle<String> source = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, data);

    Handle<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);
    if (!script.IsEmpty())
        Handle<Value> result = script->Run();
```

Test Code (obviously just for testing):

```
void test(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"test", "", 0);
}
```

But the engine returns this error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

So my question is if I even do it correct, I would be able to make the including myself I hope, but I just can't get the function to get executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code from a project that works:

```
Isolate::Scope iscope( isolate_ );
HandleScope hs( isolate_ );


Local<Object> test = Object::New(isolate_);
test->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate_, "javaScriptFunctionName"), Function::New(isolate_, CPP_FN_CALLBACK));
global_template->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate_, "test"), test);
```

That will result in an object for `window.test` with a function called `window.test.javaScriptFunctionName()`

Comment: Can you elaborate on `CPP_FN_CALLBACK` please? Is it a standard function like you see in the addon's entry point?

Comment: @JacobSchneider Yes, exactly. Just a standard cpp function that takes int v8 args as a parameter